# Is it safe to run code inside the conditional operator?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I often see and use codes like:

```
var myvar = (1 < 2) ? 3 : 4 ; //if 1 < 2 then myvar = 3, else = 4
```

But I just recently saw a code that was executing code, just like some kind of replacement for the `if(){}else{}`:

**Example:**

```
(1 < 2) ? alert("example1") : alert("example2");
```

The first thoughts that came to me were, "wow, this is like 6-7 characters shorter", "endless of possibilities" or "this made my day".

**My question:**

- Is this thing error-free and safe to use? (like, with a lot of code inside, and nested stuff)

For now, I will just keep using it in the normal way, I have the fear that if I start using it to execute pieces of code might not work.

Comment: In my opinion, you should use that ternary condition only for short instructions. For code blocks belonging to the true condition or the false condition, you should use if{} else {}, but it is just my opinion. I'm also interested in best ways to use this ternary condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some exceptions. You can't do this with:

- `break`
- `continue`
- Any block like `if`, `for`, `while`, `do`, or `try`

for example. What's more, it can mess with your order of operations:

```
x < 3 ? l = true : r = true; // Syntax error, = has lower precedence than ?:
```

But that's not the reason not to do it, it's because it's ugly. Which one is clearer to you, this:

```
if(i > 5) {
    alert('One');
} else {
    alert('Two');
}
```

or

```
i > 5 ? alert('One') : alert('Two');
```

? It's not quite right, is it? And saving characters is never a reason to do anything, really; otherwise there would be no comments or whitespace. A good minifier like Google Closure Compiler will automatically convert these for you when possible, and there are plenty of other places to save. In the end, it's just whatever you find most convenient and readable.

Also, if you do end up needing `break`, `continue`, etc. then it's going to be rather inconsistent and unattractive code.

Comment: accepted because pointed out exceptions that apparently no one else knew they exist (or at least, they all just suspiciously decided to not to mention them on their answers)

Answer (score 7):

> Is this thing error-free and safe to use? (like, with a lot of code
>   inside, and nested stuff)

Yes. However, the more code that's within it, the less readable it becomes.

I prefer to use it (the conditional operator) for short, concise statements. Anything more complex deserves an `if/else` for the sake of readability and maintainability.

Comment: I usually have 2 versions when making projects, the original with long var names and stuff and one with the less code possible. (I am only planning to use this kind of method on the second)

Comment: Interesting. Why even have the second one? To me, that'd just be more code to maintain. If you're specifically targeting javascript and minification with the second, there are things out there that do that already. :)

Comment: I am aware of the JS minifiers, I just doubt they will minify if/else with this method

Comment: Probably true, although like @minitech said, saving a few characters isn't the best reason for writing code that's hard to maintain, or maintaining two copies of code for that matter. The extra bytes you have to send over the wire will be worth the time and frustration you saved while not spending six days debugging that thirteen-statement deep conditional expression.

Comment: @ajax333221: Try [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/) with this code: `// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

if(a) {
    alert('Hello, world!');
} else {
    alert('!dlrow ,olleH');
}` ;)

Comment: @ajax333221: Or just look at the picture: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2463964/cc-example.png

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator. It's usually used for setting variables with simple strings like this:

```
var phone = old ? "blackberry" : "iPhone"
```

That much simpler than using an if:

```
var phone = "iphone"
if (old) {
    phone = "blackberry"
}
```

It's good in this context, in the example you described and as soon as it starts getting confusing or I'd definitely not recommend it!

Your example might be made better like this:

```
var msg = 1 < 2 ? "alert1" : "alert2";
alert(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also write:

```
alert( 1<2? "example1" : "example2" );
```

The ternary opertator is designed for simple cases, sometimes developers get carried away and use it to replace multiple if..else statements, e.g.

```
var someVal = foo < bar? 'yes' : bar > fum? : fum : fi != fee? fi : fee;
```

which is not a good idea IMHO.